# Error in parsing value for 'color' (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to animate a color change (font) with jQuery UI when clicking the element. 
I included the files of jQuery UI as descripted on their website.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {                  
        $('.benefits').click(function() {
            $(this).animate({color:'#b22425'}, 200);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't work. Console says:

> Error in parsing value for 'color'.  Declaration dropped.

When I'm adding an animate width change, this works fine but the color error stays.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help :-)

**EDIT**

I'm figuring out what's the problem:
I'm include the navigation and the footer with PHP:

```
<?php 
    include('navigation.php');
?>
```

When I delete this block everything works fine. But when I'm including Navigation and Footer with PHP the parsing error occurs.

Has anybody a solution?

**EDIT 2**

The Navigation and Footer Documents were "Full-Document", this means they had their own html, head, style, body ... tags. I included this documents in the body-tag of my main-document and so there were 3 complete html-documents in one.

After deleting the unnecessary tags from the navigation and footer documents **everything works fine**.

I would have seen this earlier -.-'

Thanks anyway for the comments and answers :-)

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code posted. Could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: I created a new document and copy and paste block after block from the originally document in the new one. So I found the problem, but not the solution. Please see my Edit above :-)

Comment: you can try to inspect element your page using dev tools, from there you can check what was are the contents that was being loaded and render

Comment: Yes I used this tools before. But somehow i didn't recognize my fault (see above). Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it

I created a simple html only

I downloaded the jquery colors [JQUERY COLORS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js)

and added it to the html file include the jquery library

so it would be loaded like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.color.js"></script>
```

Here is a simple [DEMO CREATED](https://jsfiddle.net/sas31ygg/)

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have figuring out whats the problem is. Please see my Edit in my post above.

Comment: @Cutter can you try to summarize up the files and how you are including each file to build your web app

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `animate` to animate colors without jQuery UI.

> All animated properties should be
>   animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties
>   that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated **but
>   background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used**.)

and

> The jQuery UI project extends the
>   .animate() method by allowing some
>   non-numeric styles such as **colors to
>   be animated**. The project also includes
>   mechanisms for specifying animations
>   through CSS classes rather than
>   individual attributes.

source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I know that I can use color animation only with Plugin. I wrote I'm trying to change the color with **jQuery UI**.